# What is the command to lock the X screen without blanking the display?

Tags: xorg, screensaver, lock-screen, xscreensaver, xlock

Years ago (decades?), I used a command that turned the mouse into a padlock icon and prevented clicking or typing, but you could still see the programs that were running.  You could blindly type your password and it would unlock.

This was useful for displaying a demo (like at a conference) but prevented user input.

Does anyone remember what the command is?

(I thought was [xlock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xlock), but either thats not it, or I can't find the option in the `man` page  to do what I want...)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, here it is.  Its [xtrlock](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xtrlock.1x.html):

> Xtrlock is a very minimal X display lock program. It doesn't
> obscure the screen, it is completely idle while the display is locked
> and you don't type at it, and it doesn't do funny things to the X
> access control lists.